# Is there any way to customize the URL for my qualtrics survey?

Tags: qualtrics

I've briefly looked around for an answer to this and it doesn't seem to be doable, but figured I'd ask on here. I am about to launch a survey on qualtrics, but would prefer, if at all possible, to customize the URL address for my survey. I would like to do this only because I plan on printing out a few advertisements to display around campus, and requiring people to then go back to their computers and type in a lengthy and complex web address is not exactly ideal.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a url shortening service like goo.gl.

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thanks!